# How can I join three mongodb collection id of one is reference of the second?

Tags: mongodb

Here is my problem statement.

I got three collections. A, B, C

A - id has a foreign key reference to B filed a_id
and B id has a foreign key reference to C field b_id

The input to my query is a-id, now how can I fetch

All A records

All B records matches a-id

All C records matches b-id

I could fetch A and its reference B records using below query, but in the same query how can I fetch all C records which has reference to b-id?

```
db.getCollection('A').appregate({
{ "$lookup": {
   "from": "B",
   "localField": "id",
   "foreignField": "a_id",
   "as": "AANDB"
}}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with the below query ;

```
db.getCollection('A').aggregate([
    { "$lookup": {
       "from": "B",
       "localField": "id",
       "foreignField": "a_id",
       "as": "AANDB"
    }},

    {"$unwind" : "$AANDB"},

    {"$lookup" : {
       "from": "C",
       "localField": "AANDB.id",
       "foreignField": "b_id",
       "as": "BANDC"
    }}
 ])
```